# Which is the best lightweight-runtime programming framework for cross platform App

Tags: silverlight, cross-platform

I'm a silverlight developer, but microsoft seems has already abandoned silverlight since 2011.
I want to develop cross platform app at least for (windows xp, 7, linux, mac os, maybe ios)
I don't like javascript or css3 or html5.
I want to develop app or ria web app.
After some research, I think Qt may be the one, But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Mono with [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp). It's cross platform. And it's C#.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for Adobe Flex. http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html

Comment: Flex Supported operating systems
• Microsoft® Windows® 7 (32 bit), Windows Vista® (32 bit), or Windows XP Professional with Service Pack 2 or 3
• Mac OS X v10.5.6–10.6 (Intel® only)
• Ubuntu 9.10
• Fedora Core 12. No 64bit windows system supported?

Comment: Looks like you can run it on Win7 64 bit running in 32-bit mode. http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/tech-specs.html

Comment: Ok, I'm doing some research on flex and adobe air, seems good!